# Bundler DSL for specifying multiple ruby engines and their versions

Tags: ruby, bundler

Let's say you have a project which wants to support only JRuby ~> 9.1.6.0 and Ruby (MRI) ~> 2.3.1, is there currently a Bundler DSL syntax to accomplish this? Ruby conditionals won't work because they create a nondeterministically-wrong `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Bundler docs](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/gemfile.5.html#PLATFORMS-platforms-), you can use `platform`.  Here's an example:

```
gem "weakling",   :platforms => :jruby
gem "ruby-debug", :platforms => :mri_18
gem "nokogiri",   :platforms => [:mri_18, :jruby]
```

You can also use a block.  This may be more relevant to you:

```
platforms :jruby do
  # Gems
end

platforms [:mri_18, :jruby] do
  # Gems
end
```

I understand it's not *exactly* what you were asking, but it seems like this would be a sufficient approach.  If this doesn't work for you, then unfortunately I don't believe there's a way to whitelist ruby versions through Bundler